Bottom Navigation View height in Android app is too much by default
I implemented a bottom navigation view in an activity, but the height of it is too much by default. How to make it normal?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.BottomNavigationHomeActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/btm_nav"
        app:menu="@menu/btm_nav_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>



It looks like BottomNavigationView is ok, the problem is in Navigation Bar, try to change its color to understand what is incorrect.

BottomNavigationView default height is this. There is no Navigation View.

This isn't answering their question, because you don't identify the problem. It would be more helpful as a comment. Please consider removing your answer and posting it as a comment instead.
